# How to convert to a matrix and plot a variable in a MATLAB file in R?

Tags: r, matlab

I have a [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) file that I want to work with, but I need to convert it to amtrix, so I can plot or do any calculations.

```
  data <- readMat('C:\\Usersfile.mat')
  str(data)
  List of 1
  $ LAND: num [1:500, 1:1300] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  - attr(*, "header")=List of 3
  ..$ description: chr "MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: GLNXA64, Created on:     Thu Oct 11 12:09:52 2012                                                "
  ..$ version    : chr "5"
  ..$ endian     : chr "little"
```

How do I plot "LAND"? Or convert it to a matrix?

Comment: Thanks for the link for wikipedia's Matlab page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have a list that contains element `LAND`, which is a numeric matrix of dimensions 500x1300. This matrix has some attributes like description, version and endian. You can access the matrix with `data[[1]]` or `data[["LAND"]]`.

Comment: This is a different question. Try `image`. If you feel my answer solved your problem, consider accepting it as the correct answer.